# After installing the Realtek driver, wired connected UI is not showing

Tags: 22.04

I'm Ubuntu 22.04.3 and the kernel version is using 6.2.0-26-generic. I'm now having a problem with UI not showing after installing that driver(2.5G/5G Ethernet Linux driver r8125 for kernel up to 6.4).

[image: 2.5G/5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 6.4]

The image in question is as follows.

[image: not showing wired connected UI]

The wired LAN is still in the UNCLAIMED state.

[image: lshw -C network]

[image: yaml]

I've tried many different methods, but I only have one YAML file. I found a lot of similar problems but couldn't find them the same as me. I think there is a problem with the YAML file, and also it does not have `00-installer-config.yaml`.